# Pulseaudio / A2DP Bluetooth don't work in system mode, but work work fine under "pi" user

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I'm running Jessie version on Raspberry Pi2. I'm trying to install Pulseaudio 8 from the source, but having problems running it in system mode with Bluez5 with A2DP support.

On startup in system-wide mode, it fails with `"module-bluez5-discover.c: Failed to load module for device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_AC_CF_85_23_8C_78"` error when I connect my phone to bluetooth.

If I simply restart pulseaudio under user account using:

```
pulseaudio -vvvv
```

and connecting the phone, everything works fine and I can play music via A2DP from the phone.

Pulseaudio is setup to run as systemd service in `/etc/systemd/system/pulseaudio.service`:

```
/usr/local/bin/pulseaudio --system --disallow-exit --disable-shm --exit-idle-time=-1 --disallow-module-loading
```

Here is the verbose log output when it fails to load module:

```
D: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: dbus: path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink, interface=org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1, member=SetConfiguration
D: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_AC_CF_85_23_8C_78/fd3 state changed from disconnected to idle
D: [pulseaudio] module-bluez5-discover.c: Loading module-bluez5-device path=/org/bluez/hci0/dev_AC_CF_85_23_8C_78
W: [pulseaudio] module-bluez5-discover.c: Failed to load module for device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_AC_CF_85_23_8C_78
D: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_AC_CF_85_23_8C_78/fd3 available for profile a2dp_source
D: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: Unknown interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable found, skipping
D: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: Unknown interface org.bluez.MediaPlayer1 found, skipping
D: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: Unknown interface org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties found, skipping
```

Here is the same section when it manages load the module when I run pulseaudio under normal user account ("pi").

```
D: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: dbus: path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink, interface=org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1, member=SetConfiguration
D: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_AC_CF_85_23_8C_78/fd6 state changed from disconnected to idle
D: [pulseaudio] module-bluez5-discover.c: Loading module-bluez5-device path=/org/bluez/hci0/dev_AC_CF_85_23_8C_78
I: [pulseaudio] module-card-restore.c: Restoring port latency offsets for card bluez_card.AC_CF_85_23_8C_78.
I: [pulseaudio] card.c: Created 1 "bluez_card.AC_CF_85_23_8C_78"
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-dbus.c: Interface org.PulseAudio.Core1.CardProfile added for object /org/pulseaudio/core1/card1/profile0
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-dbus.c: Interface org.PulseAudio.Core1.CardProfile added for object /org/pulseaudio/core1/card1/profile1
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-dbus.c: Interface org.PulseAudio.Core1.CardProfile added for object /org/pulseaudio/core1/card1/profile2
D: [pulseaudio] protocol-dbus.c: Interface org.PulseAudio.Core1.Card added for object /org/pulseaudio/core1/card1
D: [pulseaudio] module-bluez5-device.c: Acquiring transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_AC_CF_85_23_8C_78/fd6
I: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: Failed optional acquire of unavailable transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_AC_CF_85_23_8C_78/fd6
I: [pulseaudio] module-bluez5-device.c: SBC parameters: allocation=0, subbands=1, blocks=3, bitpool=2
I: [pulseaudio] source.c: Created source 1 "bluez_source.AC_CF_85_23_8C_78" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     bluetooth.protocol = "a2dp_source"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.description = "Nexus 6P"
```

The only configuration change that I did to Pulseaudio was in `/etc/pulse/system.pa`, I added this:

```
### Bluetooth Support
.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
.endif
```

I think I configured permissions correctly too:

`pulse` is added to `audio`
`pulse` is added `lp`
`pi` user is added to `pulse-access`

DBUS permissions are set as follows:

```
<busconfig>
       <policy user="root">
                <allow own="org.pulseaudio.Server"/>
                <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
                <allow send_interface="org.bluez.Manager"/>
        </policy>
        <policy user="pulse">
                <allow own="org.pulseaudio.Server"/>
                <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
                <allow send_interface="org.bluez.Manager"/>
        </policy>
        <policy context="default">
                <deny own="org.pulseaudio.Server"/>
                <deny send_destination="org.bluez"/>
                <deny send_interface="org.bluez.Manager"/>
        </policy>
</busconfig>
```

My phone is paired and connected to bluetooth stack fine.

Can anyone help to understand why Pulseaudio doesn't want to work with Bluez in system mode ?

Comment: Switching from user mode (so that a logged in user gets access to all the audio hardware) to system mode (so the the hardware is up and running all the time the machine is up) - which is what you might want in server set-ups - has proven awkward in the past - indeed Pulse Audio shares the same father as Systemd (Lennart Pottering) - so one might hope the two would work particularly well together.  It is just that the documentation may not exactly be entirely up to date and match what you have got... IMHO 8-P

Comment: I've just realized that the problem was in **`--disallow-module-loading`** flag. That prevented loading of module-bluez5-device plugin that is always loaded on-demand for a specific device and you cant load it at the startup.

Comment: That sounds right - I think that flag is a security measure particularly for the system-wide one where it can be a risk to load modules on-demand if they are not of a known reliability...

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution for my problem and it's to remove **`--disallow-module-loading`** flag. It prevents loading of **`module-bluez5-device`** as this module is always loading on-demand and can't be pre-loaded on startup via `defaults.pa/system.pa`.